# Temporary cell highlighting, reverting the original cell color

Tags: excel, vba, highlight

I want to make a macro that **Highlights the selected rows but does not change the original cell color once the highlighting is over (once the cell is not selected anymore).**
*(*Original cell color : The color of the originally specified cell.)*

and here is code that I used

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Static xRow
If xRow <> "" Then
    With Rows(xRow).Interior
         .ColorIndex=Xlnone
    End with
End If

pRow = Selection.Row
xRow = pRow

With Rows(pRow).Interior
.ColorIndex=6
.Pattern=XlSolid
End With
End Sub
```

but when I use code like this, Highlight is active, **but the original cell color is changed.**

How Can I fix it?

Comment: This `.ColorIndex=X|none` is no valid syntax. It should be `xlNone` and `xlSolid`. I recommend to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)* to avoid typos like that.

Comment: ah, it is typo sorry.. it is not |, I want to wrote l (L) .. sorry

Comment: I think you are looking for something like that: https://www.atlaspm.com/toms-tutorials-for-excel/toms-tips-for-excel-color-the-active-cell-row-or-column/ There are several tutorials on Google how to highlight cells, rows and columns. Use one of them so you don't need to invent it on your own.

Comment: "I'm not a American so I'm not good at English" - That's ok, Americans aren't good at English either. :-P

Comment: If you want to preserve the original colour you have to store it somewhere, not erase it.

Comment: @Luuklag well storing that information will be fun if `Target` is multiple cells and every cell has a different original color.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: True, but I don't see any other way if you want to highlight a row in a specific way, and then return it to its "original" state, when that original state is not cells without fill.

Comment: @Luuklag well, conditional formatting could be a solution, as it automatically reverts the original state of the cell if the condition is false. In combination with `Intersect` it could work.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thank you!! :)

Comment: @Luuklag my code erase original color..!  I knew this just a few minute ago :( thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Something that could work (did not test it) is to use conditional formatting to change the color and therefore let it always automatically restore the original color. Not sure about how good the performance of this workaround will be.

1. In a module add the following function:

   ```
   Public Function IsSelected() As Boolean
       IsSelected = Not Intersect(Application.Caller, Range("SelectedRange")) Is Nothing
   End Function
   ```
2. In your desired worksheet add the following event:

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
       Me.Names.Add "SelectedRange", Target
   End Sub
   ```
3. In the desired range add a conditional formatting with the formula:

   ```
   =IsSelected()
   ```

Comment: really appreciate for your answer, I'll do it right now :D